# Term for adverb not formed with -ly

Tags: terminology, derivational-morphology

Is there a term for adverbs that are adverb-only words, not adverbs constructed by modifying an adjective?

In other words, in English adverbs can be created by adding -ly to an adjective, so for example, we might have "happy" (the adjective) and "happily" (the adverbial construction). There are some English adverbs, however, that we might call native adverbs that only function as adverbs and are not constructed from an adjective. An example of this kind of word is "soon".

Is there a term for adverbs that are native and not constructed from adjectives?

Comment: Adverbs like: *”just, quite, so, soon, too and very”*  are not directly related to adjectives, unlike most other adverbs.

Comment: They're not all adverbs, either. Think of them as oddly-shaped gears in the grammatical machine. _Soon_ is a temporal quantifier, for instance; it requires two references to time, like a perfect, with a quantification judgement that the difference is small. _Just_ is another minimal quantifier (at least in its adverbial use -- there are a lot of others). _Too_ is a negative intensifier and _very_ is an intensifier. _Adverb_ is a wastebasket category, and this is the ugly stuff that fell to the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a term for adverbs that are adverb-only words, not adverbs constructed by modifying an adjective?

No.

Comment: @Emma Dash Greybeard, et al, are doubtless correct but if in your academic works, you started to distinguish between 'pure' adverbs and however you might describe the others, would anyone mind?  Might some take it up?